# Tiered dropdowns not showing corrctly in semantic-ui form field

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

The first item, labeled with "Examples" should expand to the right, but it doesn't get expanded over the initial droppdown. I'd guess it's because it is inside a field. Or is this possible?

http://jsfiddle.net/Lbfq2mLp/1/

```
<form class="ui form">
    <div class="ui two fields">
        <div class="ui field required">
            <label for="Examples">Examples</label>
            <div class="ui selection dropdown">
                <input type="hidden" id="Examples" name="Examples" required="required" class="ui selection dropdown" />
                <div class="default text"></div> 
                <i class="dropdown icon"></i>

                <div class="menu">
                    <div class="item"> 
                        <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
                        <span class="text">Examples</span>
                        <div class="menu">
                            <div class="item" data-value="1">
                                Example 1 <span class="floated description">1</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item" data-value="3">
                                Example 2 <span class="floated description">2</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item" data-value="2">
                                Example 2
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item" data-value="3">
                        Example 3 <span class="floated description">3</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item" data-value="4">
                        Example 4 <span class="floated description">4</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Could you please expllain what you mean by "should be expanded"? It's in an inline element, which means it takes up only as much space as its content needs.

Comment: Same issue here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34607739/semantic-ui-multi-level-dropdown-with-the-selection-class-does-not-expand