# Semantic UI Multi-Level Dropdown with the selection class does not expand

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, semantic-ui

When I try and use the dropdown with `search selection` and select a subcategory, it expands into itself and a small scrollbar appears in the dropdown. If I don't add `search selection` it seems to function just fine.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/utqz406p/4/

How do I correct this issue?

Edit: This also seems to happen with the `selection` class as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to override the default selection dropdown style.
Please use this style

```
.ui.selection.dropdown .menu {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

Comment: A note, this adds the unintended consequence of your list of items spilling through the bottom of the dropdown.

Comment: You can give specific height to your dropdown menu. So it will remain in a fixed height.

Comment: If I do that, I still get overflow out the bottom. I've posted a followup question for this though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34805672/scrolling-vertical-overflow-while-still-allowing-horizontal-overflow