# semantic UI react Dropdown inside dropdown with search closes when I click on Icon

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, drop-down-menu, semantic-ui-react

When I click on dropdown `angle down` icon, instead of opening the dropdown list **it closes the parent dropdown**.

Any ideas to prevent it?

Online demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-react-wyy9b

```
<Dropdown trigger={trigger} pointing="top right " icon={null}>
  <Dropdown.Menu>
    <Menu>
      <Items>Current Sytem Id : {"xyz"}</Items>
      <Items>Region : UK</Items>
      <Items>Environment :Prod - Design</Items>
      <Items>
        <Dropdown
          selectOnBlur={false}
          placeholder="Select"
          fluid
          search
          selection
          pointing="right"
          options={timeZoneOptions}
        />
      </Items>
    </Menu>
  </Dropdown.Menu>
</Dropdown>
```

[image]

Comment: Could you make it an online demo? Which may help others reproduce your problem very quickly!

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-react-wyy9b

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34607739/semantic-ui-multi-level-dropdown-with-the-selection-class-does-not-expand

Comment: No, I have problem with search. if I remove search prop it works as expected. but If I keep search the parent dropdown closes when I click on icon rather than opening the child dropdown